# how to check why is the website slow?

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7

I would like to check why my website using coldfusion is too slow to open sometimes, it is running on IIS-7, windows server 2008 R2.

Other websites hosted in the same server are fine.

When the site is slow, I checked Worker Processes. It shows "IsapiModule" in request. I also checked the event logs, but did not find any events related.

Truly, I do not have more idea how to check it. Can you provide any suggestions on this subject.

Thank you.

Comment: "site:stackoverflow.com coldfusion slow" (https://www.google.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20coldfusion%20slow) - plenty of other topics, not sure if any clear duplicate - but you need to add more context and info else this question is simply too vague for here. Read these other topics and see if you can get anything from them. You obviously havent even tried to google "website speed slow" and used https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=en or similar tools to determine whether it is even related at all to coldfusion (as other sites fine), nor any details of the website itself.

Comment: @DanielBrose, I tried as much as I can to check why the site is slow in both stack overflow and other websites. But I do not see any clear answer (may be cos of my knowledge) that's why I am asking in stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: Run it in your development environment with debugging enabled.  If the information there does not help, Use getTickCount() to see how long various blocks of code take to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try connector tuning:

CF10: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/tuning-coldfusion-10-iis-connector-configuration
CF11: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-11-iis-connector-tuning